# Image src - GET 404 error with meanjs

Tags: javascript, css, mean-stack, meanjs

I need your help.

I'm doing a web application using meanjs (I'm new to meanjs) the question is that when I add the following tag to my view

> img src = "../ img / logo.png"

and refresh my page, my picture is not displayed and the console gives me a **404 GET** error. Why is this happening? I'm doing something wrong?

Please help

Comment: Are you including those spaces in your string?

Comment: No the spaces are not include :S

Comment: Is that the correct file path?

Comment: I fix it, i dont know why but the path begins in the "modules" folder.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 404 Get error typically shows up when the image can't be found/doesn't exist in the directory you specified. Make sure the image is in the correct location, or adjust the src to look in the correct location.

Comment: I review my directory and it does exist. The weird thing is im giving my page a background img from the .css file and it works, but i doesnt work with my img src

Comment: I fix it, i dont know why but the path begins in the "modules" folder.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Typicaly you are in your webroot so just delete the "..", so your path reads: "/img/logo.PNG"

If that does not help, try an absolut path.

Comment: I fix it, i dont know why but the path begins in the "modules" folder.. Thank you!